# Distributed Data Store - Hazelcast Vs Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, distributed, hazelcast

We need to choose between HazelCast Or Cassandra as a distributed data store option. I have worked with cassandra but not with Hazelcast, will like to have a comparative analysis done features like :

1. Replication
2. Scalability
3. Availability
4. Data Distribution
5. Performance of reads/writes
6. Consistency

Will appreciate some help here to help us make the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

The following page and the documents on the page might help on your decision: <s>https://hazelcast.com/use-cases/nosql/apache-cassandra-replacement/</s>
https://db-engines.com/en/system/Cassandra%3BHazelcast